# Distinct with mongo and node js

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, rest, distinct

I am trying to get records using a rest service implemented with node js to populate a autocomplete of jquery. Here is the method

```
db.collection('publication', function(err, collection) {
        collection.distinct('title',{'$or':[{type:'an'},{type:'pub'}]}).toArray(function(err, items) {
                res.jsonp(items);
            });
        });
};
```

The query in mongo works ->

```
 db.publication.distinct('title',{'$or':[{type:'an'},{type:'pub'}]})
```

returns [ "Product", "Event" ]
but the result is different when I use find,
with find would be->

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51fbb2124e49d03810000000"), "title" : "Anuncio" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51fbb2ae4e49d03810000001"), "title" : "Evento" }
```

With the second way the autocomplete works, but with the first not

The error shown in node is:  object is not a function.

Finally what I need is to return a json with the records to populate the autocomplete which is populated like this:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
        source: function(req, res) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.example.com:3000/autocomplete/" + req.term ,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    term: req.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    res($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.title,
                            value: item.title
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

try to move the function part into the distinct().

`collection.distinct('title',{'$or':[{type:'an'},{type:'pub'}]},function(err, items) {
    res.jsonp(items);
});`

I ran into the same problem and I fixed my problem here:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

(search for the key word 'distinct')

It turns out that the official doc do help

Hope it helps whoever have the same problem.

Answer (score -3):

Should exclude the _id field in your search

Query:

```
db.products.find( { qty: { $gt: 25 } }, { item: 1, qty: 1, _id: 0 } )
```